# Material UI Data Grid Maximum update depth exceeded error

Tags: javascript, material-ui

i am getting this error/ warning,while entering rows of the table and it cease the screen

> **warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.**

code example is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/maximum-update-depth-exceeded-error-q19xj?file=/src/App.js)

the error occurs when i add

```
onSelectionChange={(newSelection) => {
                        select(newSelection.rows);
                    }}
```

in the DataGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `useState`, you could use `useRef`. `useRef` will not cause a re-rendering of the component because it's independent of the component lifecycle and hence will avoid the issue you're facing.

You can set and access the selected rows using `useRef.current`.

I've updated your sample component to use `useRef` instead of `useState` below and also included a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/maximum-update-depth-exceeded-error-forked-i4gyc?file=/src/App.js:0-1305). Note that in the example, the selected rows are logged in the console.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { ColDef, DataGrid, RowsProp } from "@material-ui/data-grid";

export default function App() {
  const selectedRows = React.useRef([]);

  const onSelect = (event) => {
    selectedRows.current = event.rows;
    console.log(selectedRows.current);
  };

  const rows: RowsProp = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "LuluBox_v4.8.8_apkpure.com.apk",
      type: "application/vnd.android.package-archive",
      lastModifiedDate: "2020-10-20T00:27:43.669Z",
      size: "13805 kB",
      file: { path: "LuluBox_v4.8.8_apkpure.com.apk" }
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "LuluBox_v4.8.8_apkpure.com.apk",
      type: "application/vnd.android.package-archive",
      lastModifiedDate: "2020-10-20T00:27:43.669Z",
      size: "13805 kB",
      file: { path: "LuluBox_v4.8.8_apkpure.com.apk" }
    }
  ];
  const columns: ColDef[] = [
    { field: "id", hide: true },
    { field: "name", headerName: "Name", width: 400 },
    { field: "size", headerName: "Size", width: 250 },
    { field: "lastModifiedDate", headerName: "lastModifiedDate", width: 400 }
  ];
  return (
    <DataGrid
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      pageSize={8}
      autoHeight
      checkboxSelection
      hideFooter
      onSelectionChange={onSelect}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue by comparing the previous state with the new value from   `setSelectionChange` before calling `setState`.